# Db schema is complete, can Entity Framework generate Storage Schema?

Tags: entity-framework

If I already have a database schema complete, can the entity framework somehow generate the storage schema for me?

Or if I have the classes developed, can it generate the other xml's desribing the classes and their relationships?

Answer (score 1):

Most can yes... I believe what you would be looking for is hibernate tools (tools.hibernate.com).  Toplink and other frameworks should have equivalent functionality.  You essentially provide login/db provider information, and it queries the catalog and generates xml and classes